# iPhone app is working fine on iOS 4 but crashing on Launch screen at iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, crash

**My Log report is.**

```
Dec 21 15:44:26 New-iPod-Accuretech ReportCrash[1652] <Notice>:
   Formulating crash report for process TextBook[1651] Dec 21 15:44:26
   New-iPod-Accuretech kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1651] Builtin profile:
   container (sandbox) Dec 21 15:44:26 New-iPod-Accuretech kernel[0]
   <Debug>: launchd[1651] Container:
   /private/var/mobile/Applications/CAD3777B-818F-4020-BCB7-813708315A0B
   (sandbox) Dec 21 15:44:26 New-iPod-Accuretech com.apple.launchd[1]
   (UIKitApplication:com.AccelApp.TextBook[0xfb6c][1651]) <Warning>:
   (UIKitApplication:com.AccelApp.TextBook[0xfb6c]) Job appears to have
   crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5 Dec 21 15:44:26 New-iPod-Accuretech
   com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.AccelApp.TextBook[0xfb6c])
   <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.AccelApp.TextBook[0xfb6c]) Throttling
   respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds Dec 21 15:44:26
   New-iPod-Accuretech backboardd[52] <Warning>: Application
   'UIKitApplication:com.AccelApp.TextBook[0xfb6c]' exited abnormally
   with signal 5: Trace/BPT trap: 5 Dec 21 15:44:26 New-iPod-Accuretech
   ReportCrash[1652] <Error>: libMobileGestalt
   copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from
   system version dictionary Dec 21 15:44:26 New-iPod-Accuretech
   ReportCrash[1652] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to
   /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TextBook_2012-12-21-154426_New-iPod-Accuretech.plist
   using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Comment: set relevent architechture, deployment target and currunt os oversion with ios6 hope its helps you

Comment: have you added the splash screen for iOS 6 will have the same name as that of the name of splash screen for iOS 4 but at the end it should be @2x.png means if the name of iOS 4 splash screen is xyz.png then for iOS 6 it will be xyz@2x.png and the size should be like wise changed and the pixels also.

Comment: My Splash screen is Default.png 640X960 and 72 Pix.I changed it to Default@2x.png but not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your Splash screen image `Default-568h@2x.png` . And then clean your code and remove previous build and then run again.